# Is the image of a $\sigma$-algebra necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Is the image of a $\sigma$-algebra necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra ?

I know that pre-image is always a $\sigma$-algebra, since $f^{-1}(\bigcap_iB_i)=\bigcap_if^{-1}(B_i)$ and $f^{-1}(\bigcup_iB_i)=\bigcup_if^{-1}(B_i)$.

I think, that if $f$ is not surjective, then the image is not a $\sigma$-algebra, but what if it's surjective. Do you know other counter-examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true, as s.harp pointed out in the comments.

Take $f:[0,2] \to [0,1]$ defined by $f(x) = |1-x|$, then $f$ is
surjective. Take the $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal B}=\{\emptyset, [0,2], [0,1],(1,2] \}$, then the image of ${\cal B}$ is
$\{\emptyset, [0,1],(0,1]\}$ which is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: so it is closed under complementation and countable unions but can't we make use of $f(\bigcap_i A_i)\subsetneq\bigcap_i f(A_i)$ (if $f$ is not injective)

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: It's OK, thanks.

Comment: This statement is not actually true! Take for example on $\mathbb{R}$ the $\sigma$-Algebra induced by $[0,1]$ and take $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1], x\mapsto \sin(x)$. $\{f(A)\}=\{[0,1],[0,\sin(1)],\emptyset\}$, which is not a $\sigma$-Algebra.

Comment: @s.harp: Thanks for catching my rather egregious error.

Comment: @OBDA: You may want to re evaluate the answers, mine was wrong, the error was caught by s.hard.

Comment: In [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398673/when-is-the-image-of-a-sigma-algebra-a-sigma-algebra?rq=1) the extra condition is given

Comment: *If* $f(\bigcap_i A_i) \subsetneq \bigcap_i f(A_i)$ *then* $f$ is not injective.  The proof is straightforward.  However, if $f$ is not injective it does not follow that $f(\bigcap_i A_i) \subsetneq \bigcap_i f(A_i)$, consider $f(1) = f(2) = 1$, $f(3) = 3$.  Then $f(\{1,2\} \cap \{2,3\}) = \{1\} = f(\{1,2\}) \cap f(\{2,3\})$.  What is certain is that there exists some $A_i$ such that the statement holds.  Say $x \neq y$, $f(x) = f(y) = 0$, then $f(\{x\}\cap\{y\}) = \emptyset$, but $f(\{x\}) \cap f(\{y\}) = \{0\}$.

Comment: @NathanChappell: I am missing your point?

Comment: I am being pedantic about the first comment on this thread.  It states "we can't make use of... (if ...)".  This can't be made use of at all, is the point.

Comment: @NathanChappell: I previously had an incorrect answer which is where that came from.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \,:\, A \to B$ be a function and $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on $A$.

Then you're right that *technically*, if $f$ is not surjective, $$
  f(\mathcal{A}) := \left\{f(M) \subset B \,:\, M \subset A, M \in \mathcal{A}\right\}
$$
isn't a $\sigma$-Algebra over $B$ because for all $X \in f(\mathcal{A})$ you have $X \subset f(A)$ and thus $B \notin f(\mathcal{A})$.

But one could say that you simply picked a bad codomain for $f$ in this case - if you re-define $f$ as $f \,:\, A \to f(A)$, i.e. pick a smaller codomain to *make* $f$ surjective, than that problem goes away.

If $f$ is injective, it's clear that $f(\mathcal{A})$ is always a $\sigma$-Algebra over $f(A)$, because $f$ simply amounts to a renaming of the elements of $A$ then. That leaves the question of whether that same is true for a non-injective $f$. My (not very educated) guess is that you'll still get a $\sigma$-Algebra over $f(A)$ even then, but I don't have a good argument for that at hand...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a smallest counter-example that $f(S)$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.
Define
$$
X:=\{a,b,c\}, \ Y:=\{1,2\},
$$
$$
S:=\{ \emptyset, X, \{a\}, \{b,c\}\},
$$
and
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x\ne c\\
2 & \text{ if } x=c.
\end{cases}
$$
Then clearly $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, $f:X\to Y$ is surjective, but
$$
f(S)=\{ \emptyset,  \{1\}, \{1,2\}\}
$$
is *not* a $\sigma$-algebra over $f(X)=Y=\{1,2\}$.

The example is minimal in the following sense: If $Y$ is a singleton, then $f(S)$ is trivially a $\sigma$-algebra for any $f:X\to Y$. If $f$ is bijective, then $f(S)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra as well. So $Y$ has to consist of at least $2$ elements, $X$ has at least $3$ elements. Also $f(S)$ is the smallest non-trivial $\sigma$-algebra possible.